# discord.js を使った Bot のサンプルを動かしたいがエラーが出てしまう

Tags: javascript, discord

discord.js についてです。

https://github.com/ritsu-me/V14bot の通りにやると、コマンド追加のコードを実行した際に以下のエラーが出てコマンドが追加できない。

```
~/V14bot$ node add_command.js
1個のコマンドを読み込み中
Error: Expected token to be set for this request, but none was present
    at _REST.resolveRequest (/home/runner/V14bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1340:15)
    at _REST.queueRequest (/home/runner/V14bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1300:46)
    at _REST.request (/home/runner/V14bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1266:33)
    at _REST.put (/home/runner/V14bot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1249:17)
    at /home/runner/V14bot/add_command.js:31:34
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/V14bot/add_command.js:47:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
```

自己解決しました！
返答遅れてしまいすみません！！

Comment: 何の話なのか分かるように書いてもらえませんか？

Comment: 質問は後からでも編集できるので、追加情報は直接追記してください。(今回は代わりに転記しておきました)

Comment: リンク先の Bot は一年前を最後に「サポート終了」と書かれている点は注意が必要です。`node add_command.js` を実行する前に「使い方」の手順も実施済みなのでしょうか？